# Consecutive calls to console.log produce inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console.log, angular-ui-router

Ok, I'm completely dumbfounded by this. (and I might be overlooking something obvious but...)

I have 2 consecutive calls to console.log. There isn't anything else between them

```
console.log($state);
console.log($state.current);
```

and here's an image of the produced results

[image: Console.log screenshot]

Why do the 2 produce different "current" objects? How can this happen?

---

## Context:

Those calls are made inside an ajax call while resolving a route dependencies. If you need more code or context let me know.

Confirmed the same issue in Chrome and Firefox

**Ajax call and wrapper function (no modifications whatsoever)**

```
normaCtrl.publicNorma = ['$http', '$state', '$stateParams', 'baseUrl', function ($http, $state, $stateParams, baseUrl)
{
    var id = $stateParams.id;
    return $http.get(baseUrl + "api/public/norma/" + id).then(
        function (response) {
            console.log($state);
            console.log($state.current);
            console.log($state.current.title);
            return response.data;
        }
    );
}];
```

---

## Possible related questions

- [javascript console.log displays different values on same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571003/javascript-console-log-displays-different-values-on-same-object?rq=1)
- [AngularJS: weird console.log behavior with async chrome.storage.local.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910295/angularjs-weird-console-log-behavior-with-async-chrome-storage-local-get?rq=1)

Comment: Code of your ajax request please )

Comment: Is it possible multiple ajax requests are firing? Could you show where $state is actually set?

Comment: Can other objets affects on this variables?

Comment: $state is set by ui-router, a third party library for AngularJs

Comment: @FUserThrowError yes, other objects can affect this variable. AngularJS is doing a lot of stuff under the hood

Comment: @Tivie you can try using $watch to see that other objects affects on them and how )) And i think problem in that !!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, here's the answer for those that stumble upon this.

#### Short Answer

Console.log shows deep mutable objects at the **last state of execution**, not at the **state when console.log was called**.

#### More details

Basically, when working with mutable deep objects, Console.log stores the reference to said object instead of storing an object clone.

Since there is a time gap between storing and visualization, when you click the arrow for further inspection what you're seeing is actually **the current state of the object** and not the **the state of the object when console.log was called**.

One way to always make sure you're using an "object snapshot" is to call `Json.stringify` or use `console.dir` when available.

Comment: Note that `console.dir` on Chrome may not work (I remember it did, but now it doesn't). `Json.stringify` Works.

Answer (score 1):

Weird. Is it an ECMA 5 object that has a weird getter? Still wouldn't make sense for the plain $state call. I assume there's not just something broken with your GC...

Are you sure these are the calls being logged?

Comment: Javascript is not multithreaded. The variable cannot be changing value between the console.log calls

Comment: Oops, didn't notice it was in the same portion of the promise... I should go to bed

Comment: I do. Made a project wide search for console.log, these are the only 3 matches