# get original element from ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list of items in my view with `ng-click` attached to them:

```
<ul id="team-filters">
    <li ng-click="foo($event, team)" ng-repeat="team in teams">
         <img src="{{team.logoSmall}}" alt="{{team.name}}" title="{{team.name}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm handling the click events in the `foo` function in my directive, passing `$event` as a reference to the object that's been clicked, but I'm getting a reference to the `img` tag, rather than the `li` tag. I then have to do stuff like this to get the `li`:

```
$scope.foo = function($event, team) {
   var el = (function(){
       if ($event.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {
          return angular.element($event.target).parent(); // get li
       } else {
          return angular.element($event.target);          // is li
       }
   })();
```

Is there a simple way to get the reference to the element that `ng-click` is bound to, without doing DOM operations in my directive?

Answer (score 333, accepted):

You need `$event.currentTarget` instead of `$event.target`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. It's weird that the currentTarget property in the $event object is set to null.

Comment: This is definitely strange... if you log the $event object, $event.currentTarget looks to be null.  However, if you log the $event.currentTarget reference, it shows the correct element.

Comment: I usually will use `var elem = $event.currentTarget || $event.srcElement`. Its always been more cross-browse friendly, yet I don't know if its necessary anymore.

Comment: console.log shows deep mutable objects at the last state of execution, not at the state when console.log was called. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059811/consecutive-calls-to-console-log-produce-inconsistent-results

Answer (score 13):

Not a direct answer to this question but rather to the "issue" of `$event.currentTarget` apparently be set to null.

This is due to the fact that console.log shows deep mutable objects at the last state of execution, not at the state when console.log was called.

You can check this for more information: [Consecutive calls to console.log produce inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059811/consecutive-calls-to-console-log-produce-inconsistent-results)