# Why does innerHTML returns undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

innerHTML returning undefined when  `<p></p>` tag is clicked, but i am expecting its inside html. Any guess why?

http://plnkr.co/edit/NOLTO95H5GDuG35X9NOA?p=preview

Comment: Please provide the relevant code here in the question, not in an external site. Edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass angular's `$event`

```
<p ng-click="abc($event)">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, nemo, numquam, incidunt similique quisquam dolor blanditiis quis veniam at laudantium quibusdam beatae ad ea voluptates impedit molestiae cum modi quam!
</p>
```

and get the `innerHtml`

```
$scope.abc = function(e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7eiwDzqIjD44IpTjIjYB?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Because Angular passes `$scope` objects, not the DOM elements. Since `$scope` object doesn't have the `innerHtml`, you are getting `undefined`.

You can assign a model to either an input or a textarea, then pass this model to your function instead. Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VjFXacXJMa0PpS364wOb Or, if you want to stick with playing with DOM from controller which is against the nature of Angular, you can use `$event.target`.

Answer (score 1):

You need `$event.target` or `$event.currentTarget`.

I would you should use `$event.currentTarget`, beacuse it will give you more precise element where you clicked.

**CODE**

```
$scope.abc = function($event){
  //more precise element tracking will track sub element too using $event.currentTarget
  alert( $event.currentTarget.innerHTML || $event.srcElement.innerHTML); 
  alert($event.target.innerHTML); //element tracking
}
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dKdY8Q1MRYKPhXGiuDJf?p=preview)

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107613/angularjs-get-original-element-from-ng-click) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this you can pass `$event` and get `$event.target` which is the clicked dom element

```
  $scope.abc = function($event){
    alert($event.target.innerHTML);
  }
```