# $compile returning scope instead of current element refrence

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.retryTask = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    };

$("#showloader").replaceWith(
                    $compile(
                    "<span class='iconexclaim'><img src='images/backupiconexclaim.jpg' /></span><span class='retry-btn' ng-click='retryTask(this)'>Retry</span>"
            )($scope)
);
```

The value of e is getting unexpectedly scope of controller not the image jquery object on which I'm clicking.
                );

Comment: so, where is problem? why you use jquery inside angular this way? what problem you try solve?

Comment: I want the current refrence of element on which I'm clicking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107613/angularjs-get-original-element-from-ng-click use $event.currentTarget, but using angular and jquery this way seems strange

Comment: @user3806762 but why? in most cases you not need work with dom element directly in angular

Comment: if you would not use `$complie` - then inside click handle - passed html element

Answer (score 1):

> I'm answering your specific question, **BUT continue reading**, because this is not how one should approach creating Angular apps.

To get the DOM element you need to pass the `$event` local variable that Angular creates for you:

```
<span class='retry-btn' ng-click='retryTask($event)'>Retry</span>
```

Then, you could get the element with `$event.currentTarget`:

```
$scope.retryTask($event){
   var target = $event.currentTarget;
}
```

**longer version**

You are not "thinking in Angular", so, please read the following SO question/answer first: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14994393/968155)

In a nutshell, forget about DOM inside controllers and only work with your ViewModel.

In your case, you have a simple loader that needs to appear when something is loading. So represent that with `$scope.isLoading` variable and set it to `true`/`false` when a task is running or complete. *Then*, your view can react accordingly (with `ng-show`/`ng-hide` or `ng-if`):

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, SomeSvc){
  // do some async task right away
  doTask();

  $scope.retryTask = function(){
    doTask();
  };

  function doTask(){
    // before start, set to true
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    SomeSvc.doTask()
           .then(function(data){
              $scope.data = data; // if needed
           })
           .finally(function(){
              // when finished, set to false
              $scope.isLoading = false;
           });
  }
})
```

And let the View be "driven" by the ViewModel:

```
<div ng-show="isLoading">loading...</div>
<div ng-hide="isLoading">
   {{data}}
</div>
```