# How to access a DIV's innerHTML onclick (ng-click) a button in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a simple question. I have a `<div>` and a `<button>`. I want to access the inner markup of the `<div>` inside the function I wire with `ng-click`. How can I do this *without* jQuery?

```
<div id = text-entry-view contenteditable="true"></div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click = 'sendMsg()'>Send</button>

app.controller('ActiveController', ['$scope', 'contact', '$ManageLoggedInUsername', function($scope, contact, $ManageLoggedInUsername){
    $scope.loggedInUsername = $ManageLoggedInUsername.getUsername();
    $scope.contact = contact;
    $scope.sendMsg = function(){
        //console.log("MSG :: " + <div#text-entry-view.innerHTML>);
    }
}]);
```

So I want the content of the `<div>` inside the `sendMSG` function. Kindly help.

Comment: I think this it's already answered here:
[get original element from ng-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107613/get-original-element-from-ng-click)

Comment: IOlander thanks, that solution is good. My DOM is simple but sometimes in complex nested DOM I might need to go too much parent() upwards and then find(). So I was looking for a generic solution.

Comment: Then directive is the Angular way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use plain JS in this case? Observe the following...

```
$scope.sendMsg = function() {
    var markup = document.getElementById('text-entry-view').innerHTML;
    console.log('MSG :: ' + markup);
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/62vvcbts/) - demo

---

You can also wrap your selector with `angular.element()` for access to the [AngularJS jqLite api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) e.g.

```
var markup = angular.element(document.getElementById('text-entry-view')).html()
```

Comment: scniro thank you, these are nice solutions indeed. But this is just an alternative to the jQuery approach, I mean accessing an element by ID inside any controller. I just read in an Angular tutorial that that approach is not recommended in Angular philosophy, rather we should use Directives. I am a bit confused with Directives. We generally attach Directives to a single DOM element. I was thinking about passing a reference to a DOM element into another element's directive. But don't know how.

Comment: I don't quite see any mention of custom directives in your question. I'd encourage you to accept this answer, which solves your current issue, and formulate a new question - perhaps after trying to mold this into a directive if you have not solved everything on your own at that point