# Cannot get href content on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this elements here:

```
<a href="#item1" ng-click="myfunc('arg1', 'arg2')">Item1</a>
<a href="#item2" ng-click="myfunc('arg1', 'arg2')">Item2</a>
```

"myfunc" expects 2 incoming arguments.
Now, I also need something else, which is the content of the href-attribute.

I could do one of the following

```
1 - Add a new argument to the function
2 - Add the event argument to read the content of href-attribute
```

However, in this application there seems to be many other places where the function "myfunc" is called.
This means I would need to modify them to reflect the new argument list.

So what I wonder is if there is someway in the controller to know what attribute the calling element's href contains.
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you put a service method in a controller. Move the myfunc function to a service and add the href param to it. Then from your controller and other places call this service method.

In you controller you can then get the href via :[get original element from ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107613/get-original-element-from-ng-click)

In other calls of myfunc you will have to get the href from a different source.